Nested relationships in Filament form
I have a Chapter model with a content() MorphTo relationship.
The content() relationship can be associated with a variety of models: LiveTraffic, SimulatedFlight, or Video.
The LiveTraffic and SimulatedFlight are essentially pitot models and respectively have a tracks() HasMany relationship and a prompts() HasMany relationship.
For simplicity's sake I'll take only the case of the LiveTraffic content_type.
In the ChaptersRelationManager I have the following for :
public function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            ...
            Select::make('content_type')
                ->options(Chapter::getContentTypesAsOptions())
                ->required()
                ->in(Chapter::getContentTypesAliases()),
            Group::make()
                ->relationship('content')
                ->schema(fn (Get $get): array => match ($get('content_type')) {
                    (new LiveTraffic)->getMorphClass() => $this->liveTrafficSchema(),
                    (new SimulatedFlight)->getMorphClass() => $this->simulatedFlightSchema(),
                    (new Video)->getMorphClass() => $this->videoSchema(),
                    default => [],
                }),
        ]);
}

protected function liveTrafficSchema(): array|Closure
{
    return [
        Repeater::make('tracks')
            ->relationship('tracks')
            ->defaultItems(1)
            ->schema([
                MarkdownEditor::make('transcript')
                    ->required(),
            ]),
    ];
}

When attempting selecting LiveTraffic as the content_type, I get the following error:
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Chapter::tracks()

For testing I changed the liveTrafficSchema method to not use a repeater, but a made up test text input like so:
protected function liveTrafficSchema(): array|Closure
{
    return [
        TextInput::make('test'),
    ];
}

Now, when attempting selecting LiveTraffic as the content_type, the test text input appears without any errors. When submitting the form I get the following error which seems to confirm that the content() relationship is now being taken into account:
MassAssignmentException
Add [test] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\LiveTraffic].

Hence, I'm confused with why the content() relationship seems to be ignored when nesting a repeater within it. Any help would be much appreciated!
